# Choosing Initial Neurons in Artificial Neural Network

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network

My dataset size is 800 audio files, now I want to build an Artificial Neural Network for audio classification.
I had given neurons 64 in first layer and 36 in the second layer. will there any specific number of neurons should pass in a neural network?
input shape is (826, 12), the output of the model is binary output.
[image: Here is My Neural Network]

Comment: Are your audio files all of same dimensions? If yes please paste the shape of one Audio file? You will have to modify the input_dim parameter of your first layer statement, depending upon what is the shape of your audio files. If your audio files are different sizes then you will have to preprocess your data and bring all of them to same dimensions. Pre or post padding with zeros might be a naive but valid way (in terms of Numpy) to start.

Comment: Amit I pasted dimensions of the audio please check

Answer (score 2):

Let us first start with the more straightforward part. Knowing the number of input and output layers and the number of their neurons is the easiest part. Every network has a single input layer and a single output layer. The number of neurons in the input layer equals the number of input variables in the data being processed. The number of neurons in the output layer equals the number of outputs associated with each input. 
But the challenge is knowing the number of hidden layers and their neurons.

The answer is you cannot analytically calculate the number of layers or the number of nodes to use per layer in an artificial neural network to address a specific real-world predictive modeling problem.
The number of layers and the number of nodes in each layer are model hyperparameters that you must specify and learn.
You must discover the answer using a robust test harness and controlled experiments. Regardless of the heuristics, you might encounter, all answers will come back to the need for careful experimentation to see what works best for your specific dataset.

Again the filter size is one such hyperparameter you should specify before training your network.

For an image recognition problem, if you think that a big amount of pixels are necessary for the network to recognize the object you will use large filters (as 11x11 or 9x9). If you think what differentiates objects are some small and local features you should use small filters (3x3 or 5x5).
These are some tips but do not exist any rules.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation of Keras for [sequential models](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/),

> Specifying the input shape
>
> The model needs to know what input shape it should expect. For this
>   reason, the first layer in a Sequential model (and only the first,
>   because following layers can do automatic shape inference) needs to
>   receive information about its input shape. There are several possible
>   ways to do this:
>
> - Pass an input_shape argument to the first layer. This is a shape tuple    (a tuple of integers or None entries, where None indicates
>     that any    positive integer may be expected). In input_shape, the
>     batch dimension    is not included.
> - Some 2D layers, such as Dense, support the    specification of their input shape via the argument input_dim, and    some 3D temporal
>     layers support the arguments input_dim and    input_length.
> - If you ever need to specify a fixed batch size for your    inputs (this is useful for stateful recurrent networks), you can pass    a
>     batch_size argument to a layer. If you pass both batch_size=32 and
>     input_shape=(6, 8) to a layer, it will then expect every batch of
>     inputs to have the batch shape (32, 6, 8).

I have assumed that all your audiofiles are of same dimension. I have also assumed that your X_Train is ready to go and every audio example is (826,12) dimension and your output is a single category. I have also assumed that all your audio files are vertically stacked as a tensor appropriately.

If the above is correct, then you may try the following. Without seeing the code above and below, I can't say if it will work. Please note the use of 'input_shape=  ' parameter.

```py
## ........ The code above

mmymodel = Sequential()
mmymodel.add(Dense(64, input_shape=(826,12,), init='uniform', activation = 'relu'))
mmymodel.add(Dense(36, init='uniform', activation = 'relu'))
mmymodel.add(Dropout(0.5)
mmymodel.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

## ........ The code below
```

All the best.

Comment: thanks so much Amit, i need one more clarification about values in first layer 64 and second layer 36. is 64, 36 is fixed value of weights?

Comment: I don't think they are weights..rather ... Something like number of Neurons that are present in the layer... However strictly speaking and as per the official docs (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense?version=stable) they are --> "units: Positive integer, dimensionality of the output space."